# customizing/changing the drop-down menu text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to adjust the positioning and font colour of my drop-down menu text.

My goal is to have the "title" portion of the array be in black text and on the left side of the drop-down menu, and the "type" portion of the array to be on the right side and to be grey text.

Right now all of my text is black and on the left side.

Below is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve.]

And here is my current code:

```js
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import {
  makeStyles,
  withStyles,
  ThemeProvider,
  createMuiTheme,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Chip } from "@material-ui/core";
import { emphasize } from "@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator";
import lime from "@material-ui/core/colors/lime";
import orange from "@material-ui/core/colors/orange";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textField: {
    "& input::placeholder": {
      color: "#a2a1a1",
      fontStyle: "italic",
    },
  },
});

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    tertiary: lime,
    quaternary: orange,
  },
});
// This is a step that Material-UI automatically does for the standard palette colors.
theme.palette.tertiary = theme.palette.augmentColor(theme.palette.tertiary);
theme.palette.quaternary = theme.palette.augmentColor(theme.palette.quaternary);

const getCustomChip = (color) =>
  withStyles((theme) => ({
    colorPrimary: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette[color].main,
      color: theme.palette[color].contrastText,
    },
    deletableColorPrimary: {
      "&:focus": {
        backgroundColor: emphasize(theme.palette[color].main, 0.2),
      },
    },
  }))(Chip);

const typeToChip = {
  song: Chip,
  artist: getCustomChip("secondary"),
  film: getCustomChip("tertiary"),
  show: getCustomChip("quaternary"),
};

export default function Tags() {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState([]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          disableClearable="true"
          filterSelectedOptions="true"
          multiple
          id="tags-standard"
          options={final}
          value={selectedOptions}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setSelectedOptions(newValue);
          }}
          getOptionSelected={(o, v) => o.title === v.title && o.type === v.type}
          getOptionLabel={(o) => o.title + " " + o.type}
          renderTags={(value, getTagProps) => []}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              className={classes.textField}
              variant="standard"
              placeholder="Favorites"
              margin="normal"
              //color="blue"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />

        <div>
          {selectedOptions.map((option, index) => {
            const ChipForType = typeToChip[option.type];
            return (
              <ChipForType
                key={index}
                color="primary"
                label={`${option.title}`}
                onDelete={() =>
                  setSelectedOptions([
                    ...selectedOptions.slice(0, index),
                    ...selectedOptions.slice(index + 1),
                  ])
                }
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const top10Songs = [
  { title: "Song A", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song B", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song C", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song D", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song E", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song F", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song G", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song H", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song I", type: "Song" },
  { title: "Song J", type: "Song" },
];

const top10Artists = [
  { title: "Artist A", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist B", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist C", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist D", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist E", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist F", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist G", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist H", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist I", type: "Artist" },
  { title: "Artist J", type: "Artist" },
];

const top10Shows = [
  { title: "Show A", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show B", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show C", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show D", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show E", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show F", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show G", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show H", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show I", type: "Show" },
  { title: "Show J", type: "Show" },
];

const top10Films = [
  { title: "Film A", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film B", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film C", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film D", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film E", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film F", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film G", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film H", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film I", type: "Film" },
  { title: "Film J", type: "Film" },
];

const final = [
  ...top10Songs.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, type: "song" })),
  ...top10Artists.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, type: "artist" })),
  ...top10Films.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, type: "film" })),
  ...top10Shows.map((entry) => ({ ...entry, type: "show" })),
];
```

I have been learning so much from everyone who has answered my previous questions, so thank you in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize MUI `Autocomplete` via MUI CSS customization points. Please, check out below links:

1. [Autocomplete CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css).
2. [How to override styles with styles object](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes).
3. [How to override styles with global class names](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core).
4. [How to override styles with simple css](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css).
5. Also you could read about the `renderOption` prop that allow you to rewrite `Option` view. You can find info [here](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props).

If it's not enough for you, you can check my [sandbox with an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xyhj6?file=/demo.tsx).